# Fast way of computing covariance matrix of nonstationary kernel in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, statistics, numpy, gaussian

Suppose I have symmetric positive definite covariance function $k:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is non-stationary (i.e. $k(x,y) \neq g(|x-y|)$ for any function $g$). Is there a fast way in Python given design points $(x_1,\ldots,x_n$) to calculate its covariance matrix $(k(x_i,x_j))_{i,j}$?

If the covariance function is stationary then we can compute the whole matrix at once using numpy's matrix operations and avoid slow Python loops - e.g. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556116/implementing-support-vector-machine-efficiently-computing-gram-matrix-k).

Currently my implementation is:

`dim = len(X)
kern_mat = np.zeros((dim,dim))
   for i in range(dim):
      for j in range(i+1):
         kern_mat[i,j] = kern(X[i],X[j])
         kern_mat[j,i] = kern_mat[i,j]`

Any help with speedups or otherwise is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I still would apply numpy's covaranice function using [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]).T
np.apply_along_axis(func1d=np.cov, arr=x, axis=0)
```